# grep the following pattern from curl's ftp output

Tags: curl, ftp, grep

I would like to get strings with the extenions `.rdf.gz`, e.g. `uniprot.rdf.gz` and `uniref.rdf.gz`.

My try:

```
grep 'href="rdf\/uni*\.rdf*\.gz"'
```

but i am unable to get anything.

```
$ echo $site
ftp://ftp.uniprot.org/pub/databases/uniprot/current_release/rdf
$ curl -s $site | grep 'href="rdf\/uni*\.rdf*\.gz"'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's unclear why you think your regular expression would match.  Try this instead.

```
curl -s "$site" | grep 'href="rdf/uni[^"]*\.rdf\.gz"'
```

In a regular expression, `[^a]` specifies "any character except `a`, and `*` is a postfix operator which specifies "the previous expression repeated zero or more times".

So `[^"]*` matches a substring of any length which contains characters which are not `"`.  And your attempted regex specified `href=rdf/un` (with a redundant backslash to escape the `/` which does not need escaping) followed by zero or more repetitions of `i`, followed by `.rd`, followed by zero or more repetitions of `f`, followed by `.gz`.

Notice also the double quotes around the variable interpolation `"$site"`.  In a shell script, you usually want to allow your variables to contain shell metacharacters, and interpolate them in double quotes unless you specifically want the shell to act on those metacharacters.

If you want to extract just the matching expressions within double quotes, try `sed` instead.

```
curl -s "$site" | sed -n 's%.*href="rdf/uni\([^"]*\.rdf.gz\)".*%\1%p'
```

This will only find the first `href=` if there are many matches on a line.  If that's a problem, perhaps you should do your HTML manipulation using a proper HTML parser instead.

Comment: This is probably all correct if the output were "as expected", but does not address the actual problem (wrong usage of `curl` plus completely wrong (and unnecessary) regexp) ;-)

Comment: curl -s "$site" | sed -n 's%.*href="rdf/uni\([^"]*\.rdf.gz\)".*%\1%p' works for me

Answer (score 2):

Your ftp path needs a trailing slash (otherwise you get no output), and you should use the `--list-only` switch to `curl` which will make your life way easier:

> -l, --list-only
>
> ```
>          (FTP)  When  listing  an  FTP directory,
>          this switch forces a name-only view.
> ```

On top of that, since you are connecting using `ftp`, there won't be any `href`s in your output either - just the filenames of said directory which you can easily `grep` on:

```
$ curl -s --list-only "ftp://ftp.uniprot.org/pub/databases/uniprot/current_release/rdf/" | grep '\.rdf\.gz$'
citations.rdf.gz
databases.rdf.gz
diseases.rdf.gz
enzyme.rdf.gz
go.rdf.gz
journals.rdf.gz
keywords.rdf.gz
locations.rdf.gz
pathways.rdf.gz
taxonomy.rdf.gz
tissues.rdf.gz
uniparc.rdf.gz
uniprot.rdf.gz
uniref.rdf.gz
```

Comment: +1 Oooh, I overlooked the fact that the site is an FTP server.